# How to create an editable component which looks like a TextArea?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textarea

We know that `TextArea` are not editable , so how to create an editable `component` which looks like a `TextArea` ( having the multi-line behaviour ) ?

Comment: What do you mean TextArea is not editable? By create an editable component do you mean with the attribute contenteditable="true"?

Comment: yes ! textarea has its content not editable manually ( by the keys) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TextField` and set its `setSingleLineTextArea(false)`. This requires LWUIT 1.5 or newer.

Answer (score 3):

TextArea is editable.  Here is how you can create editable text area:

```
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setEditable(true);
text.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
```

Does this not work for you?

What version of LWUIT are you using and platform are you on?

Comment: I use LWUIT 1.4 and the code you gave doesn't work ; the emulator platform is Sun Java ME SDK 3.0 on windows xp.